# Adding fixed header to responsive table

Tags: html, css

I have this **responsive** table: https://jsfiddle.net/5z0bt4yq/ i want to make the header fixed.
When I add this style to tbody in order to make the thead fixed:

```
tbody{
  height:450px;
  overflow:scroll;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
```

The table is breaking: https://jsfiddle.net/4p2h60hq/

How would you make the header fixed in this situation?